# How to get column value as percentage of other column value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question. I have a relatively huge pandas dataframe like this one:

```
df:

   Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
0     100      50       25       10
1     200      100      50       10
2     10       10       5        5
3     20       15       10       5
4     10       7        7        7
```

What I now would like to do with it is adding strings to each value as follows:
For each value in Column2, add a string displaying this value as percentage of the value in Column1. Then, for all values in Columns3 until the end (ColumnN) add to each value a string displaying this value as percentage of Column2. The final result would look like this:

```
df:

       Column1  Column2      Column3       Column4
    0     100      50 (50%)     25 (50%)      10 (20%)
    1     200      100(50%)     50 (50%)      10 (10%)
    2     10       10 (100%)    5  (50%)       5 (50%)
    3     20       15 (75%)     10 (66,6%)     5 (33,3%)
    4     10       7  (70%)     7  (100%)      7 (100%)
```

My idea of finally adding the strings to the corresponding values would maybe be something like `df['col'] = 'str' + df['col'].astype(str)`, but I don't really know how to start with it, as for example getting the percentage values for each value for example. An help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
In [95]:  (df.astype(str) + 
           ' (' + 
           df.apply(lambda x: (100 * x / x['Column1']), axis=1).astype(str) +
           '%)')
Out[95]:
        Column1      Column2     Column3     Column4
0  100 (100.0%)   50 (50.0%)  25 (25.0%)  10 (10.0%)
1  200 (100.0%)  100 (50.0%)  50 (25.0%)   10 (5.0%)
2   10 (100.0%)  10 (100.0%)   5 (50.0%)   5 (50.0%)
3   20 (100.0%)   15 (75.0%)  10 (50.0%)   5 (25.0%)
4   10 (100.0%)    7 (70.0%)   7 (70.0%)   7 (70.0%)
```

Comment: Nearly! I would like to have all column values from `column3` until `columnN` displayed as percentage of `column2`, and only the values in `column2` displayed as percentage of `column1`.

Comment: @EdChum: Not each value should be a percentage of the preceding column. Only the values in column2 should be a percentage of column1. the values of Column3-ColumnN should be percentages of Column2.

Comment: Update: Okay, I got what I wanted through slicing the dataframe in two halves, one consisting of column1 and column2, one consisting of column2-columnN. Then I applied your code to both frames separately and merged them again. Thank you!